# Boost variant visitor with an extra parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, boost-variant

I have code that resembles below.

```
typedef uint32_t IntType;
typedef IntType IntValue;
typedef boost::variant<IntValue, std::string>  MsgValue;

MsgValue v;
```

Instead of saying this,

```
IntValue value = boost::apply_visitor(d_string_int_visitor(), v);
```

**I would like to pass an extra parameter like this:** But operator() gives a compile error.

```
//This gives an error since the overload below doesn't work.
IntValue value = boost::apply_visitor(d_string_int_visitor(), v, anotherStr);

class d_string_int_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<IntType>
{
public:
    inline IntType operator()(IntType i) const
    {
        return i;
    }

    inline IntValue operator()(const std::string& str) const noexcept
    {
        // code in here
    }

    //I want this, but compiler error.
    inline IntValue operator()(const std::string& str, const std::string s) const noexcept
    {
        // code in here
    }
};
```

Comment: What you wish to do with `anotherStr` ?

Comment: Why dont you pass `anotherStr` to the constructor of `d_string_int_visitor` and then use it?

Comment: Solutions by Preatorian and Yakk are not generic; they work only because the type of the extra parameter is one of the bounded types. This is so called binary (multi) visitation. If the extra type was not a bounded type, the only solution would be to use the constructor and member variable, as pointed out by Nawaz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can bind the extra `string` argument to the visitor using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). First, add the `std::string` parameter to all of the visitor's `operator()` overloads.

```
class d_string_int_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<IntType>
{
public:
    inline IntType operator()(IntType i, const std::string& s) const
    {
        return i;
    }

    inline IntValue operator()(const std::string& str, const std::string& s) const noexcept
    {
        // code in here
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Now create a visitor to which you have bound the second `string` argument.

```
auto bound_visitor = std::bind(d_string_int_visitor(), std::placeholders::_1, "Hello World!");
boost::apply_visitor(bound_visitor, v);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/930d6cf8e4175b27)

However, a better solution would be to pass the string as the visitor's constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, Praetorian, I had a blind spot for some reason to passing it to d_string_int_visitor. But I am actually glad since this solution actually expanded my understanding of boost bind.

Comment: Why would you use `std::bind` in C++14 for this?

Comment: @Yakk Habit I guess (I still write C++03 at work). But, IMHO, this is one of those rare occasions where the lambda solution doesn't seem a lot more palatable compared to the `bind` solution.

Comment: @Praetorian my issue is that, from my perspective, `bind` is an obscure quirky function from a previous version of C++ used for niche issues; meanwhile lambdas are pretty central in modern C++.  I'd expect a C++11 developer to be using lambdas every week, if not every day, in various contexts (not just this one).  And `bind` is really quirky, esp if you start recursing (!).

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef uint32_t IntType;
typedef IntType IntValue;
typedef boost::variant<IntValue, std::string>  MsgValue;

MsgValue v;

IntValue value = boost::apply_visitor([&](auto&& one){
  return d_string_int_visitor{}(decltype(one)(one), anotherStr);
}, v);
```

assuming every overload of `d_string_int_visitor` can handle the extra parameter.

As a bonus, you can even do away with the wrapping class if you want:

```
IntValue to_int_value(IntValue v, std::string const& format) { return v; }
IntValue to_int_value(std::string const& str, std::string const& format);

IntValue value = boost::apply_visitor([&](auto&& one){
  return to_int_value(decltype(one)(one), anotherStr);
}, v);
```

where we create an anonymous lambda that forwards to a traditional set of function overloads.

The `auto&& one` and `decltype(one)(one)` is a technique to do perfect forwarding from a lambda (C++14).  You could replace the second with `std::forward<decltype(one)>(one)`, but I find the short version readable.  Unlike `std::forward`, it does the "wrong" thing with value-types, but we know that `one` is an l or r value reference.

Comment: Note that this requires at least Boost 1.58.